# How to open multiple instances of one QDialog object in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qdialog

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(640, 480)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_click)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Popup"))

    def on_click(self):
        self.dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog() 
        self.Dialog = Ui_Dialog()
        self.dialog.setModal(False)
        self.dialog.show()


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(450, 288)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Clicking on the pushButton in the mainWindow opens up a dialog which is set as non-modal. I want to modify this code so that every time the user opens the dialog, switches back to the mainWindow and clicks on the pushButton again, a new instance of the dialog should open, and the **previous instance should not close**. In this way the user should be able to open as many instances of the dialog as he pleases.

Comment: Are you asking how to literally display the *same* `QDialog` instance in another window, or just an otherwise identical instance of the `QDialog` class?

Comment: In the second case, I guess you could just store the instances in a list (or dict or similar) instead of redeclaring the same variable, i.e. in the `__init__()` define `self.dialogs = []` and in `on_click()` do something like `self.dialogs.append(QDialog())`. That should do the trick. However, when you close the dialogs, you should make sure to remove them from the list again.

Comment: Also, do not edit files generated with `pyuic` (or don't try to mimick them). Read the guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) to know how to use those files properly.